# Scrolling background in Flutter Flame

Tags: flutter, game-engine, flame

I have a list of sprite components in my game that represent three background sprite images which I would like to scroll infinitely. I initialize, update, and render the sprite components using the code below, however the sprites all move at different speeds and the game can slow down immensely at times, what is it that I am doing wrong?

Initializing:

```
List<SpriteComponent> bkgList = [];

bkgImage = await images.load('BGFull.png');
for (int i = 0; i < MAX_BKG_COUNT; i++) {
  final spr = Sprite(bkgImage);
  bkgList.add(SpriteComponent(
    sprite: spr,
    position: Vector2(640.0 * i, 0),
    size: Vector2(640, 384)
  ));
}
```

Update:

```
for (int j = 0; j < bkgList.length; j++) {
  bkgList[j].position.x -= 1.0;

  if (bkgList[j].position.x < -640.0) {
    bkgList.removeAt(0);
    bkgList.add(SpriteComponent(
        sprite: Sprite(bkgImage),
        position: Vector2(bkgList.last.position.x + 640.0, 0),
        size: Vector2(640, 384)
    ));
  }
}
```

Render:

```
for (int z = 0; z < bkgList.length; z++) {
  bkgList[z].render(canvas);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do for this is most likely to use the `ParallaxComponent` which you can find docs for [here](https://docs.flame-engine.org/main/components.html?highlight=parallaxcomponent#parallaxcomponent). For loading the spritesheet that you have in `BGFull.png` you can use the `SpriteSheet` [class](https://docs.flame-engine.org/main/images.html?highlight=spritesheet#spritesheet), and then pass in the images from there to the `ParallaxComponent`.

But from the code you have right now, the problem could be that you are not doing the initialization in the `onLoad` method, but I can't tell from your snippets.